# Change element in ttk Style layout of Tkinter Scale

Tags: python, tkinter, scale

I have a question regarding ttk Styles.
I'm applying a custom Style to the tkinter scale.
Specifically, that means, I'm using a image as slider.

Now, I want to create three different scales, where the sliders are different in their coloring. I'm storing the three pyimages in a list `self.slider = [pyimage0, pyimage1, pyimage2]`.

Starting the ttk styling with:

```
style = ttk.Style()

style.element_create('custom.Scale.trough', 'image', self.trough)
style.element_create('custom.Scale.slider', 'image', self.slider[0])

style.layout('custom.Horizontal.TScale',
              [('custom.Scale.trough', {'sticky': 'we'}),
               ('custom.Scale.slider',
                {'side': 'left', 'sticky': '',
                 'children': [('custom.Horizontal.Scale.label', {'sticky': ''})]
                })])
style.configure('custom.Horizontal.TScale', background='#ffffff')
```

Now I want to simply change through the colored sliders, when needed. However, how can I change the slider image after creating the element in style?

I tried with:

```
style.configure('custom.Horizontal.TScale.custom.Scale.slider', image=self.slider[i])
```

But it just stays on `self.slider[0]` for every scale.

Regards and thanks!!

EDIT

```
class CustomScale(ttk.Scale):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        kw.setdefault("orient", "horizontal")
        self.variable = kw.pop('variable', DoubleVar(master))
        ttk.Scale.__init__(self, master, variable=self.variable, **kw)
        self._style_name = '{}.custom.{}.TScale'.format(self, kw['orient'].capitalize()) # unique style name to handle the text
        self['style'] = self._style_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define each style individually so they have there own unique names.

The names are completely arbitrary and I had to use my own images but it works.

I've expanded the answer to demonstrate usage.

```py
for i,a in enumerate(["red", "green", "blue"]):

    style.element_create(f'{a}.Scale.trough', 'image', self.trough)
    style.element_create(f'{a}.Scale.slider', 'image', self.slider[i])

    style.layout(f'{a}.Horizontal.TScale',
                  [(f'{a}.Scale.trough', {'sticky': 'we'}),
                   (f'{a}.Scale.slider',
                    {'side': 'left', 'sticky': '',
                     'children': [(f'{a}.Horizontal.Scale.label', {'sticky': ''})]
                    })])
    style.configure(f'{a}.Horizontal.TScale', background='#ffffff')

self.redslider = ttk.Scale(self.master, from_ = 0, to=255, style = "red.Horizontal.TScale")
self.redslider.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the fast answer. I have two questions regarding your solution: 1. Why not only use i as an iterable? Why a? 2. I use an CustomScale class for the implementation in my Tkinter app. How can I adapt the class to meet your solution? (I edited my original post)

Comment: With your first question, enumerate 'i' is `int` while the 'a' is a `str` so `f{a}.Scale` translates into `red.Scale` or whatever and `self.slider[i]` accesses the image. As for your second question, I'll have to check it out. My test code was simply to apply a style to each `Scale`, and it worked first time. I could modify my answer to include the `Scale` declarations, that might help?

Comment: Hi @Derek. Thanks, understood! Yes, I think the only problem in the CustomScale is the ```self._style_name = '{}.custom.{}.TScale'.format(self, kw['orient'].capitalize())```, because the "custom" part is still in there, which is substituted by the name of coloring in your solution. Of course, I'd be grateful for your help!